# Days between two date in vba

Tags: vba, excel, date, time, type-conversion

I have two dates. I want to count number of days between.

```
date_today = Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy")

test_date = Format(wsM.Range("M10").Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")

result= DateDiff("D", date_today, test_date)
```

I see in debug:

[image: debug]

The result is wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: what's the results? At work, images are blocked.

Comment: should be visible now, it's 539

Comment: I put these dates into two different date calculators I found on google and they both resulted in 539.

Comment: Check your computer's international settings and make sure it is set to dd/mm/yyyy format.

Comment: You shouldn't convert your dates to String. A simple `DateDiff("y", Now(), CDate(wsM.Range("M10").Value))` should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got answer from other forum:

```
Dim date_today As Date, test_date As Date
Dim result As Long
date_today = Date

test_date = wsM.Range("M10").Value

result = DateDiff("D", date_today, test_date)
```

It's tested and it's working.